# Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sorry if my question has been answered somewhere already, but all the other posts about "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data" did not help me.

I'm trying to run the following code, but it gives this error: *Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x*

```
library(tidyverse)

demand <- function(q) (q - 10)^2
supply <- function(q) q^2 + 2*q + 8

x <- 0:5

chart <- ggplot() +
  stat_function(aes(x), color = "Demand", fun = demand) +
  stat_function(aes(x), color = "Supply", fun = supply)
chart
```

What's wrong here?

The output should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Edited my answer with the `xlim()` needed to show the curves as required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `?ggplot2::stat_function()`, this geom does not require `data = ...`. This because "`stat_function() computes the following variables: x values along a grid [and] y value of the function evaluated at corresponding x`". The problem is related to the way you use `x` inside `aes()`. Please, look at the code below:

EDIT: I have added the possibility to use the `x` object to set the x-axis.

```
library(ggplot2)

demand <- function(q) (q - 10)^2
supply <- function(q) q^2 + 2*q + 8

x <- 0:5

chart <- ggplot() +
  stat_function(aes(color = "Demand"), fun = demand) +
  stat_function(aes(color = "Supply"), fun = supply) +
  xlim(min(x), max(x)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend",
                     values = c("Demand" = "red", "Supply" = "#24C6CA"))
chart
```

The output:

[image]

Is it what you are looking for? Note the use of `xlim()` to set the range of the x-axis.

Comment: This works to get the wanted output, but I struggle to understand why I can't add the input to the demand and supply models via giving values to x.

Comment: Maybe it is just not the right geom. If you use your vector `x` to compute a vector `y` using your functions you can then use `geom_points` and/or `geom_lines`. And still add the `stat_function` on top of it.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I figured it out. This works:

x <- data.frame(x = c(0:5))
chart <- ggplot(data = x, aes(x)) +
  stat_function(aes(color = "Demand"), fun = demand) +
  stat_function(aes(color = "Supply"), fun = supply) 
chart

Comment: @MetaPhilosopher You are welcome :) may I ask why you need to use this `x` object absolutely?

Comment: Well, I want to be able to use this piece of code as a template for other situations where my x's, which stand for quantities in the model, have different values.

Comment: @MetaPhilosopher thanks for the answer, I have added a little line to take this into account :)